# Python if-statements when the condition variable is boolean

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

If I have an boolean variable such as:

```
condition = True
```

And it is used in an if statement, is there any diference between the uses (other then readability)? For example:

```
if condition:
    pass

if condition == True:
    pass

if condition is True:
    pass
```

Comment: Don't use `elif` when the condition is the opposite of the `if` condition. Just use `else:`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp That's OK because `if condition` succeeds for all the other values.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, just threw that in for good measure. Anyway, now that I see the dupe, my comment is not needed.

Comment: I just added the elif statement to explain better what was my point. But i'll edit it out, because it realy doesn't make much sense to be there